# multiprocessing pickling error: _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function myProcess at 0x02B2D420>: it's not the same object as __main__.myProcess

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I'm reading and applying code from the python book and I can't use multiprocessing in simple example that you can see below:

```
import multiprocessing


def myProcess():
    print("Currently Executing Child Process")
    print("This process has it's own instance of the GIL")
    print("Executing Main Process")
    print("Creating Child Process")


myProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=myProcess)
myProcess.start()
myProcess.join()
print("Child Process has terminated, terminating main process")
```

My platform is Windows 10 64 bit and using if __name_ == "__main_" : doesn't work in this case. What's wrong here? This code should work in python version 3.5 and above. Python version I use is 3.7. Full error message below:

```
C:\Users\Xian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe "C:/OneDrive/Utilizing sub-process.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OneDrive/Utilizing sub-process.py", line 25, in <module>
    myProcess.start()
  File "C:\Users\Xian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Xian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Xian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Xian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\Xian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function myProcess at 0x02B2D420>: it's not the same object as __main__.myProcess
```

Comment: You overwrite the function named `myProcess` with the process you create, hence the target is in `multiprocessing` and not in `__main__`. Also, why does `__name__ == '__main__'` not work? Under windows you actually _have_ to use it in this context

Comment: Actually, not quite correct. The target still is the function `myProcess` but it cannot be pickled from your module due to the fact that `__main__.myProcess` is the process at the point you call `start()`.

Comment: in some cases I read (I think here on stackoverflow) that __name__ == '__main__' is needed on windows for multiprocessing to work but yeah in this case it's function (myProcess) name. I don't want to change code too much from the book because I'm learning and I'm not sure what does what. Unfortunately it looks like code wasn't tested in this book.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
def test()
    import multiprocessing

    multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork")

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=xxx)
    p.start()
```

[python multiprocessing Contexts and start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)

Comment: The `fork` method is available on Unix platforms only.